# In Javascript how could I loop over a table and its nested rows and generate a CSV?

Tags: javascript, html, export-to-csv

**The problem**

I'm trying to loop over a table which has nested row and export all of the data to a CSV. This is the data structure:

- Profile
- Profile > Linked users

The data is coming from an API as an array with nested objects that I then loop over and output to the view.

**My attempt**

My current logic is partially working but interprets any table rows with nested rows as one combined row.

I can loop over the table rows but can't exclude the combined rows so I get the following output:

**Current result**

- Tom
- Tom Jack Sam Alex (combined)
- Jack
- Sam
- Alex
- Josh

**Expected result**

- Tom
- Jack
- Sam
- Alex
- Josh

**Codepen example**

Here's a basic example that logs the output: https://codepen.io/joshuarobertson/pen/xxQjmgV

**Table data structure**

This is a basic example of the table structure:

```js
/*
 ** Export table data to CSV
 */
function exportToCsv() {
  // Get the table element
  var table = document.querySelector('table')

  // Create an empty array to store the cell values
  var cellValues = []

  // Get the table headers from the thead section
  var headerValues = []

  table.querySelectorAll('thead th').forEach(function(header) {
    headerValues.push(header.textContent.trim())
  })

  // Add the header values to the main cell values array
  cellValues.push(headerValues.join(','));

  // Function to process the rows recursively
  function processRows(rows) {
    rows.forEach(function(row) {
      var rowValues = []

      // Check if the row has nested tables
      var nestedTables = row.querySelectorAll('table');

      if (nestedTables.length > 0) {
        // Process nested tables recursively
        nestedTables.forEach(function(nestedTable) {
          var nestedRows = nestedTable.querySelectorAll('tr')
          console.log(nestedRows[0].innerText)
          console.log(nestedRows[1].innerText)
          console.log(nestedRows[2].innerText)
          processRows(nestedRows)
        });
      } else {
        // Loop over each cell of the row
        row.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(function(cell) {
          rowValues.push(cell.textContent.trim())
        });

        // Add the row values to the main cell values array
        cellValues.push(rowValues.join(','))
      }
    })
  }

  // Process the top-level table rows
  var topRows = table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')
  processRows(topRows)

  // Log the comma-separated list to the console
  console.log(cellValues.join('\n'))


  // Combine each row data with new line character
  csv_data = csv_data.join('\n')

  // Call this function to download csv file
  downloadCsv(csv_data)
}

/*
 ** Download CSV
 */
function downloadCsv(csv_data) {

  // Create CSV file object and feed
  // our csv_data into it
  csv_data = new Blob([csv_data], {
    type: "text/csv"
  })

  // Create to temporary link to initiate
  // download process
  const temp_link = document.createElement('a')

  // Download csv file
  temp_link.download = "GfG.csv"
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(csv_data)
  temp_link.href = url

  // This link should not be displayed
  temp_link.style.display = "none"
  document.body.appendChild(temp_link)

  // Automatically click the link to
  // trigger download
  temp_link.click()
  document.body.removeChild(temp_link)
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Town</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tom</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>London</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Jack</td>
              <td>30</td>
              <td>Glasgow</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Sam</td>
              <td>40</td>
              <td>Belfast</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Alex</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>Hull</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Josh</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>Cardiff</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why is there a nested table with 3 separate table bodies? How should the nesting be handled in terms of the final CSV data? What is the latter supposed to look like? Suggestion ... just loop over any of the outer table's table rows ... `document.querySelector('table').querySelectorAll('tr')`.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+nested+table+to+csv+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Hi @PeterSeliger, this is a reduced example but in my project the nested tables have been used for a consistent layout. I have a separate JS function that expands the nested rows (not needed for this example). The final CSV data should include each nested row without the combined rows. I will try your suggestion now.

Comment: @PeterSeliger looping over the outer table's table rows produces the same result. I've updated my question with the expected outcome, hopefully that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: _"The data is coming from an API as an array with nested objects"_ - might make more sense to work with that data directly then, rather than transforming it into a table structure first, only to then parse the data out of that table again.

Comment: @CBroe that could be an approach but in my project there are custom filters that can disable and remove columns and rows without making another request. So the export needs to be reactive to what's in the DOM. The solution provided works well, but thanks for your suggestion too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code generates csv based on html and filters on results that have 3 entries

```js
const headers = [...document.querySelector('thead tr').children]
  .map(c => c.textContent)

const data = [...document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')]
  .map(tr => [...tr.children]
    .map(c => c.textContent))
  .filter(c => c.length === 3)

const csv = [headers, ...data].join('\n')

console.log(csv)
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Town</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tom</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>London</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jack</td>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>Glasgow</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sam</td>
                            <td>40</td>
                            <td>Belfast</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Alex</td>
                            <td>50</td>
                            <td>Hull</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Josh</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Cardiff</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Perhaps add some description?